# ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I moved my local db to mLab's free tier and I'm getting an error I didn't get before. `ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel`

The error is catching from line `user.save()`.
Could you take a look and please show how to fix it? I'm so lost...

```
// Confirm password.
// Execs after requiresAuth permission resolver.
const confirmPassword = ({ user, inputs: { password } }) => {
  // Validate args.
  validate([required, isLength], 'PASSWORD', password)

  // Required for graphql. Expects a promise.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      if (!isMatch) return reject(error('CONFIRM_PASSWORD_FAILED'))
      return resolve(user)
    })
  )
}
```

---

```
// Compare submitted plain text password with the salted and hashed version.
    UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, callback) {
      return bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (isMatch) {
          this.account.authStrikes = 0
          this.account.lastConfirm = Date.now()
        } else {
          this.account.authStrikes += 1
          if (this.account.authStrikes === 3) {
            this.account.status = 'locked'
            require('../resolvers/auth')
              .createUnlockAccountToken({ userId: this._id })
          }
        }
        return this.save()
          .then(() => callback(null, isMatch))
          .catch(err => callback(err))
      })
    }
```

Comment: You're mixing callbacks and promises, which is essentially the root of the problem. But why would this need to call `save()` anyway? Why is "comparing" needing to persist anything? It just seems misplaced in here, even though the other code can be corrected anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry but could you show an example?

Comment: I could, but I'd really like to know why you think `save()` even belongs here. I really don't think it should be here at all even though I suspect your justification revolves around the "locked" thing. And I'm also concerned about where this `confirmPassword` function is actually being called from

Comment: @NeilLunn Yep exactly, I am calling `confirmPassword` at few different spots where user is required to either login or confirm password if last confirm is past due. I left `user.save()` in here because it felt weird to save after callback when in those functions there was nothing 'visibly' modified... I guess I just don't know how to keep it clean... Could you show me an example?

Comment: i was working on nodejs application suddenly application crashed and written in console, Can’t save() the same doc multiple times in parallel
than i review my code i got one mistake
exists.save();
exists.save().then((data:any)=>{
}).catch((error:any)=>{
})